# Cloudfront and S3 folder problems

Tags: amazon-s3, hosting, amazon-cloudfront, aws-lambda-edge

I have created one bucket and one cloudfront distribution.
I followed this resource https://opsdocks.com/posts/multiple-websites-one-s3/ because I am going to host 3 different domains with only one bucket.

I have this folder structure in my bucket:

```
folder1 (domain1)
--- index
--- web1
--- web2

folder2 (domain2)
--- index
--- web1
--- web2

folder3 (domain3)
--- index
--- web1
--- web2
```

I used the lambda@edge function of the resource:

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    request = event['Records'][0]['cf']['request']
    request['origin']['s3']['path'] = "/"+request['headers']['host'][0]['value']
    request['headers']['host'][0]['value'] = request['origin']['s3']['domainName']
    return request
```

It works correctly with the path of the following type: folder1/web1.
However, I have tried so hard to include in the script a behavior when accessing to folder1/ gets a redirection to folder1/index but it downloads an empty file all of the time.

I have made a lot of tests changing the function in so many ways but I do not know why is still doing the same behavior.
Thank you